# How to get selected value using @Html.DropDownList & pass it into the partial view in ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: c#, html

I am creating ASP.NET web application to see patient data. There is dropdown of Doctor's list.
According to Doctor patient list should shown.
I used partial view for to show patient data, @Html.DropDownList for Dropdown.
I want the selected Doctor ID to pass into the partial view.

I tried some logic it works for var id = 1 but after changing dropdown value partial view no updating.
Please can anyone suggest some changes or new logic.

**PatientController.cs**

```
using HospitalManagement.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HospitalManagement.Controllers
{
    public class PatientController : Controller
    {
        private PatientDbContext db = new PatientDbContext();
        private DoctorDbContext db1 = new DoctorDbContext();

        public ActionResult Data()
        {
            ViewBag.Doctors = db1.doctors.ToList();
            ViewBag.Patients = db.patients.ToList();

            ViewModel mymodel = new ViewModel();
            mymodel.Doctors = db1.doctors.ToList();
            mymodel.Patients = db.patients.ToList();
            return View(mymodel);
        }

    }
}
```

**Data.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Data";
    List<HospitalManagement.Models.Doctor> doctors = ViewBag.Doctors;
    List<HospitalManagement.Models.Patient> patients = ViewBag.Patients;
}

<h2>Patient's Data</h2>
@Html.DropDownList("DoctorsList", new SelectList(doctors, "doctor_id", "doctor_name"),
    new { @class = "btn btn-light dropdown-toggle mt-3 mb-3" })

@{var id = 1;}
@Html.Partial("PatientList", patients.Where(x => x.doctor_id == id))

<script>
    $('#DoctorsList').change(function () {
        id = $('#DoctorsList option:selected').val();
    })
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("ready!");
    });
</script>
```

**PatientList.cshtml** <-- partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<HospitalManagement.Models.Patient>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Patient Data";
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.patient_id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.patient_name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.date_of_registration)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.doctor_id)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.patient_id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.patient_name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.date_of_registration)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.doctor_id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.patient_id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.patient_id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/dashboard/index">Back to the list</a>
</div>
```